# More then 53-bit floating point precision in php?

Tags: php, floating-point, precision, mandelbrot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I work with high precision decimals in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8485932/how-do-i-work-with-high-precision-decimals-in-php)

For a mandelbrot fractal I need more floating-point precision then just 53-bit in php. Is this possible? I've read this post about php floating-point but it's hard to understand: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/01/10/php-vs-bigint-vs-float-conversion-caveat/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking at floating point numbers, I think you're probably limited to PHP's native double precision (53-odd bits of precision) floats or the [BC Math stuff](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php) (arbitrary precision).

They also have a [GMP extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php) as well but I've had the GMP stuff die violently on me in low memory situations, something I find unforgivable in a general purpose library. Still, if you avoid those situations, it *is* blindingly fast. The PHP package only seems to support the integer side of GMP currently so you'd have to work with scaled integers (ie, fixed point) to get non-integer functionality. That may be more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: Do you know when the php gmp wrapper supports floating-points? Unfortunately my function doesn't work with integer only?