# Float type adding extra digit in database structure

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My database structure for a currency table has one row for the value of the currency

I am trying to set it at 1.2000000
but after I do it changes to 1.20000005

This is causing my some grief with some other parts of my code that checks for decimals.

the structure is set to: float(13,8)

Comment: so what is the question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I work with high precision decimals in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8485932/how-do-i-work-with-high-precision-decimals-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the type in database from float to decimal if You need to hold the value of currency

Please check better explanation why not to use floats
[Use Float or Decimal for Accounting Application Dollar Amount?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61872/use-float-or-decimal-for-accounting-application-dollar-amount)

Comment: I thought of that but it was already set to float from when the software was originally developed so I didnt want to change too many things. I changed the amount of decimals to 4 from 8 though and that seems to have fixed it without causing any issue.

Comment: @Sackling in this example yes, but when You try to insert another value the problem will still exists, so changing to decimal is best way I think, you no need to do anytching more just change type

Comment: I add that problem is not a database, it's a PHP what makes float numbers "griefed". Changing column to decimal(8,4) in sql will suppress this weirdness. see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148937/compare-floats-in-php)

Comment: It's IEEE754 what makes float numbers "griefed" - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems